# Problems with logo positioning

Tags: html, css, position, center

*URL: http://ruslanchik.ru/go*

Hello, I faced with specific difficulties trying make my logo centered on page. I tried *margin:auto* and *vertical-align:middle*, *text-align:center*, but it doesn't help at all.

Style of div:

```
#logo {
width:100%;
top:25%;
margin:auto;
position:absolute;
width:667px;
height:32px;
background:url(../i/logo.png) no-repeat;
```

Needed: horizontally centered logo.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and move #logo out of the center tag. You don't need the center tag anymore.

```
#logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
    background: url(../i/logo.png) no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: @ruslanchik I see on your website that the css isn't as I have written here. set height to 190px and remove position:absolute and top:25%. If you want, I'll post a screenshot from editor.